# Can SQL server handle multiple queries at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can a SQL Server handle multiple queries at the same time? Assuming each query is looking into different partition of the data?

Comment: All (reasonable) databases can handle multiple queries at the same time.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/

Comment: The answer is mostly yes, but knowing the context for your question would help.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes on that question. The answer seems obvious, but it's an interesting question, and the mechanics behind isolation are very interesting.

Comment: @Loïc hover your mouse over the downvote arrow - it doesn't show any research, there is loads of information about this available on the web. Its unclear, because not really a yes or no question/answer, as it depends why the question is being asked. And its not useful to future readers as its without context.

Comment: oh cool, I didn't know that mouseover downvote trick thanks :)
Then yes, I must agree, this question doesn't show any research or effort, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can, that's why there are **locks**.

You are looking for the **Isolation** part of **ACID**, which means : Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability.

This is an official article on that topic : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15